# Sails.js and node-cron (trying to make the scheduler work on my birthday reminder app)

Tags: sails.js, node-cron

I'Ve been having troubles scheduling reminder on my birthday reminder app. I tried using cron, got it running semi-way and it im still getting errors. I need some help.

this is the error on my terminal: okay I think I may have gotten cron to start working on my birthday reminder app but I'm getting this error on my terminal:

info: Starting app...

info: ·• Auto-migrating...  (drop)
info:  ✓ Auto-migration complete.

myCronJob
error: The bootstrap function encountered an error *AFTER* it already ran once!  Details: TypeError: this.source.replace is not a function
at CronTime._parse (/Users/odozi/Code/Sails/birthday-reminder-application/node_modules/cron/lib/cron.js:402:29)
at new CronTime (/Users/odozi/Code/Sails/birthday-reminder-application/node_modules/cron/lib/cron.js:46:9)
at new CronJob (/Users/odozi/Code/Sails/birthday-reminder-application/node_modules/cron/lib/cron.js:565:19)
at /Users/odozi/Code/Sails/birthday-reminder-application/node_modules/sails-hook-cron/src/index.js:15:28
at Array.forEach ()
at Sails. (/Users/odozi/Code/Sails/birthday-reminder-application/node_modules/sails-hook-cron/src/index.js:14:14)
at Sails.emit (node:events:525:35)
at Sails.emit (node:domain:489:12)
at emitter.emit (/Users/odozi/Code/Sails/birthday-reminder-application/node_modules/sails/lib/app/private/after.js:56:26)
at afterBootstrap (/Users/odozi/Code/Sails/birthday-reminder-application/node_modules/sails/lib/app/private/initialize.js:78:11)
at /Users/odozi/Code/Sails/birthday-reminder-application/node_modules/sails/lib/app/private/bootstrap.js:119:12
at /Users/odozi/Code/Sails/birthday-reminder-application/node_modules/sails/lib/app/private/bootstrap.js:93:18
at Sails.runBootstrap (/Users/odozi/Code/Sails/birthday-reminder-application/node_modules/sails/lib/app/private/bootstrap.js:97:5)
at Sails.wrapper [as runBootstrap] (/Users/odozi/Code/Sails/birthday-reminder-application/node_modules/@sailshq/lodash/lib/index.js:3282:19)
at Sails.initialize (/Users/odozi/Code/Sails/birthday-reminder-application/node_modules/sails/lib/app/private/initialize.js:67:9)
at Sails.wrapper [as initialize] (/Users/odozi/Code/Sails/birthday-reminder-application/node_modules/@sailshq/lodash/lib/index.js:3282:19)
at /Users/odozi/Code/Sails/birthday-reminder-application/node_modules/sails/lib/app/lift.js:66:13
at /Users/odozi/Code/Sails/birthday-reminder-application/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:3883:24
at replenish (/Users/odozi/Code/Sails/birthday-reminder-application/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:1014:17)
at iterateeCallback (/Users/odozi/Code/Sails/birthday-reminder-application/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:998:17)
at /Users/odozi/Code/Sails/birthday-reminder-application/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:972:16
at /Users/odozi/Code/Sails/birthday-reminder-application/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:3888:13
Running cron job
Running cron job
Running cron job
Running cron job
Running cron job
Running cron job
Running cron job
Running cron job
Running cron job
Running cron job
Running cron job
Running cron job
Running cron job
Running cron job
Running cron job
Running cron job
Running cron job
Running cron job
Running cron job
Running cron job
Running cron job

I'Ve checked GPT, it says something about the _parse function in the lib.
[Result from GPT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5jdNQ.png)

I could also provide my GitHub link:

This is what my cron folder in my api dir looks like:

```
type here

const cron = require("node-cron");

cron.schedule("* * * * *", () => {
  console.log("Running cron job");
});

module.exports = cron;
```

AND the bootstrap file

```
type here

module.exports.bootstrap = function () {
  const cron = require("node-cron");
  const cronConfig = sails.config.cron;

  for (const jobName in cronConfig) {
    const job = cronConfig[jobName];
    // job.start();
    console.log(jobName);
  }
};
```

I'Ve been on this thing for weeks now. I'd appreciate any help. Thanks!

I've deleted and re-installed the package several several times.

P:S: I'm expecting the cron to work seamlessly thereby looking at my local db for birthdays saved by the user and sending an email.